# find domain controllers in another domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Following on from some other posts that this forum has helped me with.....

I have a situation where we have 2 AD domains where users can be created and i am trying to search for a GC that has a copy of that account so I can create the mailbox. Replication takes about 20  minutes so I am trying to remove that wait time.

The script I have is below and my problem seems to be that it only searches GCs in the current domain and I will need it to search which ever domain is specified.

So we have 2 domains, both of which a spread across the same 2 sites and I am looking to find the user account on a GC in the correct domain but it only seems to search the current domain (domain1).

Does anyone have any ideas?

TIA

Andy

```
$ADUserName = "user1"
$Domain = "domain2"
$ADDomain = "dc=domain1,dc=domain,dc=co,dc=uk"

import-module activedirectory

$GCs = get-addomaincontroller -filter {(domainname -eq $Domain) -and (isglobalcatalog -eq $true) -and (site -eq "Site1") -or (site -eq "Site2")} 
write-host $domain -f green

foreach ($GC in $GCs)
{
    $GCendpoint = "{0}:3268" -f $GC.HostName
    $SearchResult = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(samaccountname=$ADUserName))" -Server $GCendpoint -searchbase $ADdomainDN -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if(@($SearchResult).Count -gt 0){
        $ADServer = $GC.hostname
        Write-host "Found $ADUsername on "$ADServer -f green
        set-adserversettings -viewentireforest:$true -preferredserver $ADServer
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find global catalogs by domain in an easier way:

```
$domain1GlobalCatalogs = (Get-ADForest -Identity "domain1.local").GlobalCatalogs
$domain2GlobalCatalogs = (Get-ADForest -Identity "domain2.local").GlobalCatalogs
```